# where can I find all the methods of UIATarget class?

Tags: ios, javascript

I used to consult Apple Developer page "UI Automation JavaScript Reference for iOS" but now the page redirects to a search page of apple that I cant find any information that was provided on the reference I want. I also google my doubts and all the results redirects me to the page that doesnt exist anymore. Does anyone know where can I consult all the methods of UIATarget class?

The page Im referring is https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/

Comment: Please rewrite your question leaving out the part that only Apple employees would be able to answer ("What happened to...").  If your question is about UIATarget class, that's what you should be asking about.  You'll get better answers that way.  - From Review

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a saved copy of this page from July 2012 at archive.org:
    https://web.archive.org/web/20120523220502/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/web/20120606031156/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html

It seems like `UI Automation` was probably replaced by [Javascript for Automation (JXA)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508) around Yosemite.